# Number of checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox

How to rewrite this code from jQuery to vanilla JavaScript? I need to see how many checkboxes are checked. The problem is I do not know how to remove unchecked checkboxes from the total score.

```
$(function () {
    var countChecked = function () {
        var n = $("input:checked").length;
        $(".output").text(n);
    };
    countChecked();

    $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", countChecked);
});
```

What should I do next?

```
var box = document.querySelectorAll('form input');
var par = document.querySelector('.output');
var great = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
    box[i].addEventListener('click', countIt);
    function countIt() {
        for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
            if ( box[i].checked ) {
                great++
                par.innerHTML = great;
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it already count only the checked boxes ?

Comment: Well `$("input:checked").length` already gives you the count, what else do you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the `great` variable each time you count (for example by moving it inside the `countIt` function).

```
var box = document.querySelectorAll('form input');
var par = document.querySelector('.output');

function countIt() {
    var great = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
        if (box[i].checked) {
            great++;
        }
    }

    par.innerHTML = great;
}

for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
    box[i].addEventListener('click', countIt);
}
```

You can also move the `countIt` function definition out of the loop and the same with `innerHTML` setting.

Comment: Thank you for your help)